# drop-down list in C# issue

Tags: asp.net

drop-down list in C#.net not showing the items it supposed to show!
i hv a drop-down list that suppose to show image names from a folder, but it is not doing that!
i dont have errors when launching the .aspx file!
buuuuuut when i get output there is only empty dropdown list!

---

this the ManageProducts.aspx codes are:

Name:

Type:

" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductTypes] ORDER BY [Name]">

Price:

Image:

Description:

---

and this the behind codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;


public partial class PagesNew_ManagementPages_ManageProducts : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if(!IsPostBack)   //this baby makes the data not come every time the pg is refreshed , 
    //postback=refresh page
    GetImages();
    }

    private void GetImages()
    {
        try
        {
            //get all filepaths
            string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Img/Products/"));

            //get all filenames and put them in a stupid array....yeah DSA days
            ArrayList imageList = new ArrayList();
            foreach (string image in images)
            {
                string imageName = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
                imageList.Add(imageName);
               // see the Array in dd viwe datasource and refresh
                ddImage.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddImage.DataBind();


            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            lblResult.Text = e.ToString(); 
        }



    }

    protected void ddImage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


 }
```

Comment: why is there a problem here !!!!

Comment: Probably your dropdown need to know what images should be shown. You don't set its DataSource

Comment: @Steve what do u mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to bind your datalist outside of the for loop.

```
ArrayList imageList = new ArrayList();
foreach (string image in images)
{
    string imageName = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
    imageList.Add(imageName);
}
ddImage.DataSource = imageList;
ddImage.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
ddImage.DataBind();
```